# Fill NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I have a dataframe

```
TIMESTAMP P_ACT_KW PERIODE_TARIF P_SOUSCR
2016-01-01 00:00:00 116 HC 250
2016-01-01 00:10:00 121 HC 250
2016-01-01 00:20:00 121 NaN 250
```

To use this dataframe, I must to fill the NaN values by (HC or HP) based on this condition:

```
If (hour extracted from TIMESTAMP is in {0,1,2, 3, 4, 5, 22, 23}
```

So I replace NaN by HC,
else by HP.
I did this function:

```
def prep_data(data):
    data['PERIODE_TARIF']=np.where(data['PERIODE_TARIF']in (0, 1,2, 3, 4, 5, 22, 23),'HC','HP')
    return data
```

But I get this error:

```
 ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-23-c1fb7e3d7b82> in <module>()
 ----> 1 prep_data(df_energy2)

 <ipython-input-22-04bd325f91cd> in prep_data(data)
       1 # Nettoyage des données
       2 def prep_data(data):
 ----> 3     data['PERIODE_TARIF']=np.where(data['PERIODE_TARIF']in (0, 1),'HC','HP')
       4     return data

 C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py
 in __nonzero__(self)
     890         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
     891                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
 --> 892                          .format(self.__class__.__name__))
     893 
     894     __bool__ = __nonzero__

 ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) to test for membership:

```
data['PERIODE_TARIF']=np.where(data['PERIODE_TARIF'].isin([0, 1,2, 3, 4, 5, 22, 23]),'HC','HP')
```

`in` doesn't understand how to evaluate an array of boolean values as it becomes ambiguous if you have more than 1 `True` in the array hence the error

Comment: Thanks, another error : 
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable